# How to make a script run more than once in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, scala, loops

I'm trying to make a script in my HTML code run more than once, but it seems that the  tags run only once. Even when I place it in a loop.

Please see my code below:

```
<ul>
        @for(stock <- stocks) {
            <li>@stock</li>
            <li id="stockOutput">Test</li>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               var apiUrl = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=@stock&interval=1min&apikey=***************';
                fetch(apiUrl).then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                    }).then(data => {
                        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
                        document.getElementById("stockOutput").innerHTML = myJSON;
                        });
                </script>
        }
    </ul>
```

I'm writing this project in Scala, HTML, and Javascript.

Comment: Take a look at your response object and see if it makes sense

Comment: for a security reasons I would censore the API key if it is your private key, you may be banned by making it public (banned by your stock supplier)

Comment: Ah thanks for the heads up Trueman, I completely ignored that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setTimeInterval function and give it how many ms you need;
example

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

this code will run each 3 seconds

Comment: well depends on what u wanna do.

Comment: u can even use event when user does something